# Adding a "Word" in php code

Tags: php

So, I know title is super confusing but I didn't know how to word it.

In the following code, the word "View:" is placed and displayed properly on the page.

```
<div class="myuserpropageview">View:<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pageview', true );?> </div>
```

In the following code, how can achieve the same thing? (where do I place "View:"?)

```
$output .= '<div class="dhvc-woo-view">';
$output .= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pageview', true);
$output .= '</div>';
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any word (html) you put between the single quotes will be echoed when you echo `$output`.
so you can do this:

```
$output .= '<div class="dhvc-woo-view">View: ';
$output .= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pageview', true);
$output .= '</div>';
```

or

```
$output .= '<div class="dhvc-woo-view">';
$output .= 'View: ';
$output .= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pageview', true);
$output .= '</div>';
```

it's the same.

Comment: I didnt know you can check "Accept" answer. Had to search on google how to accept an answer! Anyway Thanks Ituk! haha

Comment: haha yea, i'm also new here. it's fine!